# ANTLRv4 TestRig unable to find my Lexer class

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I'm just starting out with parsers and the like, and I'm trying to build my own little logical language for a game I've been toying with. I set up ANTLR4 on my machine and ran through the test code just fine - by running

```
grun Hello r -gui
```

I was able to get the appropriate output.

However, when I compile the following grammar and try running

```
grun garden expr -gui
```

I get a

> NoClassDefFoundError: gardenLexer(wrong name: parser/gardenLexer)

gardenLexer.class exists in the folder, but for some reason ANTLR can't seem to see it.

```
grammar garden;

@header
{
package parser;
}

expr
      : '(' expr ')'
      | 'not' expr
      | expr 'and' expr
      | expr 'xor' expr
      | expr 'or' expr
      | 'exactly' INT property
      | 'atleast' INT property
      | 'atmost' INT property
      | 'exists' INT property
      | property 'adjacent' property
      | property 'leftof' property
      | property 'rightof' property
      | property 'above' property
      | property 'below' property
      ;

property
      : SIZE
      | COLOR
      | TYPE
      | SIZE COLOR
      | SIZE TYPE
      | COLOR TYPE
      | SIZE COLOR TYPE
      | 'water'
      | 'any'
      ;

WS
      : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
INT
      : '0'..'9'+;
TYPE
      : 'stone'
      | 'statue'
      | 'plant'
      ;

COLOR
      : 'black'
      | 'white'
      | 'gray'
      ;

SIZE
      : 'small'
      | 'large'
      ;
```

Comment: The header directive in your grammar is probably to blame. It's been a while since I worked with ANTLR, and I don't have it installed, but try either 'grun parser.garden expr -gui` or try removing the package directive from your grammar.

Comment: You never need the `@header{package ...;}` directive in ANTLR 4. Use the `-package` command line argument to ANTLR 4 instead.

Answer (score 4):

If your antlr-generated classes belong to a package you should call grun as

```
grun *packageName*.garden expr -gui
```

from "classes" folder (not sources)